# Asp.Net MVC Changing Resource Values Without Clearing Cache Manually

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multilingual

In my Asp.Net MVC application users are coming from another system and I'm logging them in like below.

```
IAccount account = null;

if (userType == UserType.SystemUser)
    account = _accountService.CheckSystemUser(userId);
if (userType == UserType.Employee)
    account = _accountService.CheckEmployee(userId);

if (account == null) throw new Exception(ErrorMessages.UserNotFound);

var roles = account.Roles.ToArray();

var principalModel = new CustomPrincipalViewModel
{
    UserId = account.UserId.ToString(),
    FullName = account.FullName,
    Roles = roles,
    Language = account.Language
};

var userData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(principalModel);
var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, principalModel.FullName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), false, userData);
var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

SetCulture(account.Language.CultureCode);

return Json(new { isSuccess = true, userFullName = account.FullName });
```

And setting current culture like this with `SetCulture` method.

```
private void SetCulture(string culture)
{
    culture = CultureHelper.GetImplementedCulture(culture);
    var cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];
    if (cookie != null)
    {
        cookie.Value = culture;
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cookie = new HttpCookie("_culture")
        {
            Value = culture,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1)
        };
    }
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

And my view pages I'm setting text values from Resource files like below.

```
<span class="pageButton"> @Global.Cancel </span>
```

But when I change user language from other system and log in again to my system, all texts are still in previous language. After I refresh my page with ctrl+F5 everything looks in true language.

Is there a way to force to load page texts in new language without clearing cache manually ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in cookie `var cookie = Request.Cookies["_culture"];`, still keep old value, clean it when you logOff or when you try to log-In again

And you can use also `Thread.CurrentThread` to set culture

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```